# Testing Akka Actors

Tags: testing, akka

I have the following actor definition:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
    override def preStart(): Unit = {
        super.preStart()
        self ! M1("from M1")
    }

    def receive = initial("initial state")

    def initial(str: String): Receive = {
        case m1: M1 =>
            self ! M3("from M3")
            context.become(active(str))
        case m2: M2 => println(m2.str)

    }

    def active(str: String): Receive = {
        case m1: M1 => println(m1.str)
        case m3: M3 => println(m3.str)
        case str: String => println(s"string in active is ${str}")
    }
}
```

I was under the impression that I could just use sbt to test my actor and I went ahead and did the following in my sbt console:

```
val f = Await.result(myActor ? M1("hello world"), 10 seconds)
```

I was left with a Timeout Exception. How can I test this actor? I mean, I just want to see what gets printed out to the console!

Comment: You are performing an `ask` operation (via `?`) but nowhere in your code are you replying back to the sender of the `M3` message you are expecting a response for

Comment: Why can't I see those println statements?

Comment: Your initial `receive` impl only expects a `String` but in `preStart` you are sending an `M1` which just passes through because it's not matched on

Comment: Sorry that was a type. I edited my post! Still I do not see anything being printed out

Comment: What is it exactly you are trying to accomplish.  You are calling `wait` (which is weird to explicitly invoke something you are describing as a `Receive` PF) passing in a String but none of the match statements in `wait` expect a String

Comment: I was going crazy here! Thanks for pointing that out. I now modified my post! It looks fine!

Comment: When I run the code above, I get the following printed: from M1 followed by from M3. Where did the Hello World go?

Comment: You are encountering a race condition.  When you create an actor (via `actorOf`), you get a ref back that isn't necesarrilly completely started just yet.  In this case, the `M1("hello world")` is queued into the mailbox before the `self ! M1("from M1")` that is happening in the `preStart`

Comment: But then where did the hello world message go?